# How to center map on marker click to show whole InfoWindow

Tags: android, maps, center, marker

Ok, by default on marker click, marker is centred on the map. The problem is, that i have high infoView, inflated from layout, and it show out of map bounds. What can i do, to center pin horizontaly, and position it below map center, to make infoWindow visible.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So I ended up with this solution, it works like a charm. I`m opening infoWindow after animation.

```
int zoom = (int)map.getCameraPosition().zoom
CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new 
LatLng(arg0.getPosition().latitude + (double)90/Math.pow(2, zoom), 
arg0.getPosition().longitude), zoom);
map.animateCamera(cu,500,null);
```

Comment: This is great.  I'm curious where the math comes from.  Were these just appropriate values you came up with that would incorporate the zoom level, or was there theory involved in which these numbers are specific?

Comment: I knew that world width is 256dp * 2^zoomLevel.
arg0.getPosition().latitude was my pin latitude.
90 was just a factor that i needed, and I got it by calculating distance i want to move camera at certain zoom level, let's say that at zoom 14 i needed to move camera by ~0,006 degree to have infoView visible. So based on this i calculated factor 90, and this is working:)

My infoView was too big to fit in map if pin was centered, so i wanted to animate zoom to point above my pin.


One thing... it is working for integer zoom levels, so i just cast it to integer.

Comment: wonderful trick. Don't ask me why but it worked better for me if I use 150 instead 90. mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(selectedMarker.getPosition().latitude + (double)150/Math.pow(2, zoom), selectedMarker.getPosition().longitude), zoom));

Comment: after what animation?

Comment: @PabloCegarra I meant map centering animation.

Answer (score 10):

GoogleMaps uses [Web Mercator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator) which extremely distorts the data in high latitudes because it essentially  maps our planet to a square. Thanks to this, the further you are from equator, the bigger error you introduce to some simplified calculations.

**We will instead let Android deal with those for us ;)**

In the following text `mGoogleMap` is your `GoogleMap`. We will set a
`onMarkerClickListener` in which we open the `InfoWindow` *(as in the default implementation of onMarkerClickListener)* and then instead of
centering on the marker itself, we recalculate the camera center position according to the **GoogleMap projection**.

```
mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            // Calculate required horizontal shift for current screen density
            final int dX = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.map_dx);
            // Calculate required vertical shift for current screen density
            final int dY = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.map_dy);
            final Projection projection = mGoogleMap.getProjection();
            final Point markerPoint = projection.toScreenLocation(
                    marker.getPosition()
            );
            // Shift the point we will use to center the map
            markerPoint.offset(dX, dY);
            final LatLng newLatLng = projection.fromScreenLocation(markerPoint);
            // Buttery smooth camera swoop :)
            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(newLatLng));
            // Show the info window (as the overloaded method would)
            marker.showInfoWindow();
            return true; // Consume the event since it was dealt with
        }
    });
```

`animateCamera()` moves the camera to the calculated position smoothly, you can jump to the new position with `moveCamera()`.

We also need to add the two dimensions, `map_dx` and `map_dy`, to the resources:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Where to shift the map center when user taps on marker -->
    <dimen name="map_dx">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="map_dy">-100dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

And we're done, this method (unlike some others) work well all over the map, even close to the Earth's poles.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the adapter of your infoWindow:

```
@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

View infoWindowLayout = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_info_window_layout, null);

int width = display.getWidth() (I put here a "*2/3" too to not fill the whole screen, but this is your choice);

LinearLayout infoWindowSubLayout = (LinearLayout) infoWindowLayout.findViewById(R.id.myInfoWindowSubLayout);

android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

infoWindowSubLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);

return infoWindowLayout;
}
```

And the layout file for this in my case is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/myInfoWindowLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/..."
android:orientation="horizontal"
... >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/myInfoWindowSubLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    ...>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        CONTENT HERE
    </LinearLayout>

   CONTENT HERE TOO
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Well, this works for me, feel free to rewrite it

Comment: Well, my view was a little more complicated, could not scale it down this way, but if someone is using scale aware layout than this would be good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following perfectly working solution

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker)
            {
                int yMatrix = 200, xMatrix =40;

                DisplayMetrics metrics1 = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics1);
                switch(metrics1.densityDpi)
                {
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                    yMatrix = 80;
                    xMatrix = 20;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                    yMatrix = 100;
                    xMatrix = 25;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                    yMatrix = 150;
                    xMatrix = 30;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
                    yMatrix = 200;
                    xMatrix = 40;
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
                    yMatrix = 200;
                    xMatrix = 50;
                    break;
                }

                Projection projection = mMap.getProjection();
                LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();
                Point point = projection.toScreenLocation(latLng);
                Point point2 = new Point(point.x+xMatrix,point.y-yMatrix);

                LatLng point3 = projection.fromScreenLocation(point2);
                CameraUpdate zoom1 = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point3);
                mMap.animateCamera(zoom1);
                marker.showInfoWindow();
                return true;
            }
        });
```